# Change winforms control at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have inherited user controls in the following manner:

ControlBase

|__ControlInherited1

|__ControlInherited2

`ControlBase` contains methods and properties that are overridden in each inherited control, but it has no other controls at all. Inherited controls override the base methods and have sub-controls on them and totally different from each other.

I have the `ControlBase` added to the form, and I want to change it to either `ControlInherited1` or `ControlInherited2` depending on run-time conditions.

I'd like to take advantage of the inheritance so I do not have to add different routines for every inherited class

I tried the simple `controlBase = new ControlInherited1();` line, but the objects of `ControlInherited1` control is not displayed on the form.

Is such visual inheritance even possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what *different routines* means in your context? If you add a derived class, you can always cast down to their `baseclass` and access the common methods (`([SomeControlInheriting] as baseclass).[CommonMethod]((...))` or `.[CommonProperty] = (...)`). If a method is specialized, no casting will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that even if your new control is inherited from the base control, there's no automatic way of applying the existing properties to the new one you're adding with the call `controlBase = new ControlInherited1();`. In essence, you'll lose all information about the original control when overwrite the original variable by creating a new instance of the `ControlInherited1` class and setting it as the value of `controlBase`.

The correct way to replace an existing control would be to first remove the existing control and then adding the other one to the form, like following:

```
this.Controls.Remove(controlBase);
this.Controls.Add(newControl);
```

On top of this, you'll have to do some manual work to make sure all the properties that you want to persist from the original control are applied to the new (replaced) one.

Comment: The problem with this is that the name of the control will be `newControl`, and that's how I'll need to refer to it further on. However, everything in the code is called via `controlBase`, so my code will not work.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that after removing and adding the control I just needed to add `controlBase = newControl;`. Now I can refer to everything via the usual code.